# ADB server version does not match client error. Cannot start daemon

Tags: android, adb, appium

MAC:~ abcd225$ adb -H10.XX.XX.XX -P8080 devices
List of devices attached
adb server version (39) doesn't match this client (40); killing...
ADB server didn't ACK
Full server startup log: /var/folders/_n/9sr_21n571j3zertvgbbp4nl8v1_n7718/T//adb.1431542824.log
Server had pid: 10907
--- adb starting (pid 10907) ---
adb I 08-28 10:49:08 10907 313697 main.cpp:56] Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.40
adb I 08-28 10:49:08 10907 313697 main.cpp:56] Version 4797878
adb I 08-28 10:49:08 10907 313697 main.cpp:56] Installed as /Users/csdf3224/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb
adb I 08-28 10:49:08 10907 313697 main.cpp:56]
error: could not install *smartsocket* listener: listening on specified hostname currently unsupported

Any idea what this error is trying to tell me? I am trying to remotely connect to devices via adb on my MacBook, to a windows server where the devices are connected.

Comment: Not duplicate, please remove.

Comment: anyone know how to do this?